# Pass user to SharePoint 2013 when integrating document from BizTalk 2013 SharePoint adapter

Tags: integration, sharepoint-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm able to create a user specifically for integrations and enter the corresponding credentials when configuring my WSS send port. This works fine, however, as expected, when I view the document in SharePoint, the "Modified By" user on the document is the integration user.

Is there a way that I can set the modified by field in SharePoint dynamically? That is, the user that actually initiates the integration? (I have the user's information available when the adapter sends the document to SharePoint, I'm just unsure of how to tell SharePoint to impersonate the integration as a specific user).

Comment: Maybe add the original user to an extra column in the SharePoint list, this is the easiest solution. Otherwise you'll need to configure Single Sign On (SSO), which requires the user to submit the document under his own credentials, but is much more work